# Fail to decompose and make stationary time series

Tags: python, time-series, statistics, forecasting, python-3.x

I am looking for some suggestions for my time series.
I am dealing with the column "Temperature (C)" from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/muthuj7/weather-dataset) dataset. I am trying to make it stationary in order to do some forecasting on it.

Here's what I did until now:

1. I uploaded the dataset and set date&hour as index
2. I pruned by dataset: I kept only records which have 12:00:00 as hour
3. I tried to compute the adf test to understand if the data is stationary or not. It told me it was non-stationary.

Therefore, I tried two things:

1. Differenciate the data --> adf resulted "non-stationary"
2. Decomposed the data --> again I got "non-stationary"

What should I do? I am stuck...
Here's my code of this last part:

```
# adf test part
adftest = adfuller(ts, autolag='AIC')
output = pd.Series(adftest[0:4], index=['Statistic', 'p-value', '# Lags Used', '#Observations Used'])
for key, value in adftest[4].items():
    output['Critical Value (%s)' % key] = value
# result:
# Statistic                        -2.685398
# p-value                           0.076599
# #Lags Used                       14.000000
# #Observations Used             1813.000000
# Critical Value (1%)              -3.433962
# Critical Value (5%)              -2.863136
# Critical Value (10%)             -2.567619
```

I think this indicates that I have non-stationary data, as p-value > critical value (any). **Is this correct?**

I then tried to differenciate:

```
one_diff = ts.diff(periods=1)
```

But, again, calculating the adf test told me this result is non-stationary (even differenciating like 6 times).

Looking online, I read about decomposition. Therefore, I tried it here:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model='additive')
```

Here's the result:

[image: result of decomposition]

I think nothing's working, but I don't know how to do it properly. Can you help me please? **What am I doing wrong?**

Thank you in advance.